# Nextcord, why can't i do this in @tasks.loop?

Tags: python, nextcord

Nextcord accepts a list of datetime.time in @tasks.loop but i need to change the list. I tried to do this:

```
class peter_teste(commands.Cog):
    
    def __init__(self, bot):
        super().__init__()
        self.bot = bot
        self.peter.start()

    def peter_times(self):
        peter_hours = []
        #change the default list
        return peter_hours

    @tasks.loop(time=self.peter_times())
    async def peter(self):
        #do something
```

I get the error "self is not defined" in @tasks.loop(time=self.peter_times())

Comment: you can't have self in a method decorator, move `peter_times` outside of the class and just use it as a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use `peter_times` in the decorator, it can't a method of the class, as the decorators are processed before the class is initialized, (so `self` is not defined there). You can set up those times outside the class, or set them up in a [before_loop](https://nextcord.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/tasks/index.html#nextcord.ext.tasks.Loop.before_loop) and change the interval there.

[change_interval](https://nextcord.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/tasks/index.html#nextcord.ext.tasks.Loop.change_interval) can be used to change the times in the middle of execution.